# Using repeated measures anova: Am I right?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, biostatistics

We have just finished an experiment, where we had samples distributed into 6 groups and each group receiving a different treatment. Each group had 5 samples, with 20 replicate measurements taken per sample (they do not represent timepont difference, but mainly replicates). The data looks something like this

[image: Data Sample]

I am stacking the data and making R chew on it, so that the final input looks something like this...

[image: DataInputToR]

Now, We want to see if there is  difference in TotalActivity (the values in the trial variable in the first table) Between the groups represented in FinalID (6 groups).

I factor the relevant fields after importing the CSV and perform the repeated measures ANOVA in R like so

```
Data <- within(Data, {
FinalID <- factor(FinalID)
AnimalID <- factor(AnimalID)
Trial <- factor(Trial)
})

aov.out = aov(TotalActivity~FinalID*Trial + Error(AnimalID), data=Data)
PostHoc <- with(Data,pairwise.t.test(TotalActivity,FinalID,p.adjust.method="bonferroni"))
print(summary(aov.out))
print(PostHoc)
```

Okay, now the confession is that statistics is not my forte, and am a bit confused how to set up my repeated measures. I googled it and found a couple of formulas like so

```
aov.out = aov(TotalActivity~FinalID*Trial + Error(AnimalID), data=Data)

aov.out = aov(TotalActivity~FinalID + Error(AnimalID/FinalID), data=Data)
```

I have no idea what's the right formula to use, or even if any f the above are right statistical technique... suggestions please?